# How to remove the tailing nil/empty values in array

Tags: ruby

How to remove the tailing nil/empty values in array?

I want to remove the tailing nil values in the following array,

So the array size may become 125, not 127

```
        ...
        [123] "Conc_Net_LE_8_TDR_Long_Other",
        [124] "Conc_Net_LE_8_TDR_Short_Other",
        [125] "Contract_Units",
        [126] nil,
        [127] nil,
```

Comment: `array.delete_if { |elem| elem.blank? }`

Comment: @Salil Ruby don't have `blank?` It is *Rails* method.

Comment: While `blank?` technically is not a "ruby" method the source is actually very simple to patch `class Object; def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self
end; end`. Then `array.delete_if(&:blank?)` will work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

```
["foo", nil, ""].grep(/./)
# => ["foo"]
```

Comment: Haha.. It is nice. How did you discover it? :) +1

Comment: I meant how did you find out the trick ? That . Doesn't match with nil .. "".. Etc ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit It is pretty much clear that `nil` will not match `Regexp#=~`. The problem was whether passing `nil` to `Regexp#=~` would raise an error.  Since `Regexp#=~` is used in `Regexp#===`, and `===` is used in case statement, which can usually take any object without raising an error, I could make a guess that passing `nil` to `Regexp#=~` would not raise an error. Once I made a guess, all I needed to do was to test it.

Comment: Nice thing you taught me today... Impressive.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
new_array = array.compact.delete("")
```

`#compact` will remove all `nil` objects, and using `#delete`, you can delete all *empty string* object(`""`). You can also do :

```
array.delete_if { |elem| elem.nil? || elem.empty? }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array#compact](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-compact), or the bang version `compact!` to modify the called object to remove the `nil` elements.

```
> arr = [1, nil]
> arr.compact
 => [1]
```

To remove `nil` **and** empty you can use [Array#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-reject) or also the bang version `reject!`

```
arr = [1, nil, ""]
arr.reject { |i| i.to_s.empty? }
=> [1]
```

Comment: How you would take care of _empty_ ? :p

Comment: what if `i` is `[]`.. hehehe :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested to remove only the tailing nil and empty sequence, maybe you can do something like this

```
array = ["1","2","3",nil," ","4",nil,nil, ""]
rev = array.reverse
while rev[0] == nil or is_empty_sequence?(rev[0])
  rev.shift
end
p rev.reverse #Output -> ["1","2","3",nil," ","4"]
```

where `is_empty_sequence?` is a method where you declared what are the empty sequence.